# Insert into each server directive files dinamicaly NGINX

Tags: nginx, conf

my current settings are:

My nginx `http` settings are like ..

```
http{
    # ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/.conf*;
}
```

and each server `conf` files I have this include:

```
server{
    # top settings..
    include common.conf;
    include wordpress.conf;
    # etc ..
}
```

So, what I'd like to use and have is something like this:

```
http{
    # ...
    for each server in (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf){
        include common.conf;
        include wordpress.conf;    
    }
}
```

I'd like to define that `common.conf` and `wp` settings to be automaticaly included in each server, to define it in `http` block, and not to include it in each `server` block ..

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can use your configuration management tool to generate nginx configurations.

Comment: What tools are you refering @MichaelHampton? I'm using pure text editor to change nginx config

Comment: You should be using a configuration management system such as ansible, chef, puppet, etc., to manage your systems. These can easily generate complex configurations of the sort you want. nginx alone will not.